# pass more than one function to a callback

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

Given that :

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=(2*multiprocessing.cpu_count()+1)) as executor:
        for netelement in DOC['code']['info']['dev']:
            job = executor.submit(bgp_communities.do_lookup, netelement)
            job.add_done_callback(functools.partial(bgp_communities.do_data_wrangling, DOC))
```

is it possible to pass a 2nd function (like `bgp_communities.do_data_wrangling`) as a parameter to the callback of the `future` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. But if you want more than one function to be called when the job is done, just make another call to `job.add_done_callback`.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=(2*multiprocessing.cpu_count()+1)) as executor:
    for netelement in DOC['code']['info']['dev']:
        job = executor.submit(bgp_communities.do_lookup, netelement)
        job.add_done_callback(functools.partial(bgp_communities.do_data_wrangling, DOC))
        job.add_done_callback(...)
```

see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.add_done_callback):

> add_done_callback(fn)
>
> Attaches the callable fn to the future. fn will be called, with the future as its only argument, when the future is cancelled or finishes running.
>
> **Added callables are called in the order that they were added** and are always called in a thread belonging to the process that added them. If the callable raises an Exception subclass, it will be logged and ignored. If the callable raises a BaseException subclass, the behavior is undefined.
>
> If the future has already completed or been cancelled, fn will be called immediately.